# MiniMagick::Error ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed

Tags: 14.04, apache2, rails, imagemagick

When I SSH into my instance and run convert -version or mogrify -version it recognizes ImageMagick but when I try to upload an image, I am receiving an error.

**conver -version**

```
convert -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

**mogrify -version**

```
mogrify -version
Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2012 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP
```

**Error**

```
FATAL -- : 
MiniMagick::Error (ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed):
  mini_magick (4.3.6) lib/mini_magick/configuration.rb:125:in `cli'
  mini_magick (4.3.6) lib/mini_magick.rb:38:in `graphicsmagick?'
  mini_magick (4.3.6) lib/mini_magick/tool.rb:110:in `executable'
  mini_magick (4.3.6) lib/mini_magick/tool.rb:94:in `command'
  mini_magick (4.3.6) lib/mini_magick/tool.rb:79:in `call'
  mini_magick (4.3.6) lib/mini_magick/tool.rb:40:in `new'
  mini_magick (4.3.6) lib/mini_magick/image/info.rb:129:in `identify'
  mini_magick (4.3.6) lib/mini_magick/image/info.rb:97:in `raw'
  mini_magick (4.3.6) lib/mini_magick/image/info.rb:31:in `[]'
  mini_magick (4.3.6) lib/mini_magick/image/info.rb:41:in `block in cheap_info'
  mini_magick (4.3.6) lib/mini_magick/image/info.rb:40:in `fetch'
  mini_magick (4.3.6) lib/mini_magick/image/info.rb:40:in `cheap_info'
  mini_magick (4.3.6) lib/mini_magick/image/info.rb:15:in `[]'
  mini_magick (4.3.6) lib/mini_magick/image.rb:285:in `[]'
  ckeditor (4.0.11) lib/ckeditor/backend/carrierwave.rb:57:in `read_dimensions'
  carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:84:in `block in process!'
  carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:76:in `each'
  carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb:76:in `process!'
  carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in with_callbacks'
  carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `each'
  carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/callbacks.rb:18:in `with_callbacks'
  carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/uploader/cache.rb:122:in `cache!'
  carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:329:in `cache'
  carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/mount.rb:163:in `data='
  carrierwave (0.10.0) lib/carrierwave/orm/activerecord.rb:39:in `data='
  ckeditor (4.0.11) app/controllers/ckeditor/application_controller.rb:13:in `respond_with_asset'
  ckeditor (4.0.11) app/controllers/ckeditor/pictures_controller.rb:12:in `create'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process'
  actionview (4.1.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call'
  browser_details (0.0.6) lib/browser_details.rb:59:in `call'
  route_downcaser (1.1.4) lib/route_downcaser/downcase_route_middleware.rb:46:in `_call'
  route_downcaser (1.1.4) lib/route_downcaser/downcase_route_middleware.rb:9:in `call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
  warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call'
  remotipart (1.2.1) lib/remotipart/middleware.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
  activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
  airbrake (5.0.2) lib/airbrake/rack/middleware.rb:22:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  lograge (0.3.4) lib/lograge/rails_ext/rack/logger.rb:15:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.5) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:77:in `process_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:142:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:110:in `main_loop'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick/blob/master/lib/mini_magick/configuration.rb

```
   def cli
      @cli ||
        case processor.to_s
        when "mogrify" then :imagemagick
        when "gm"      then :graphicsmagick
        else
          raise MiniMagick::Error, "ImageMagick/GraphicsMagick is not installed"
        end
    end
```

Comment: Has this ever been resolved?